# Printing DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, printing, datagridview

I have set up a form, where I have a DataGridView with bookings, currently I can print the DataGridView but only what is on display, so any data that is only visible by scrolling down is not printed.

How do I alter my code so when i click the print button everything (including data that is viewed by scrolling) is printed to the page?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project
{
    public partial class frmViewBookings : Form
    {
        public frmViewBookings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 mainpage = new Form3();
            mainpage.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void frmViewBookings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet1.Booking' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.bookingTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet1.Booking);    
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
            this.dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
        } 

        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not using Reporting?

Comment: hmm good idea, i will try reporting if i cant do this. i am new to this so need to read up on reporting. any suggestions?

Comment: I wanted to do the same but I ended using Microsoft Reports. Its not hard really. You have to create a class for your DataGridView datasource (if you dont have it). Then, in the report, you create a Tablix with a DataSet with that class. Finally, in runtime, you pass the DataSource list from the DataGridView to the report as a parameter and it´s done. If you want to do it this way tell me and I can give you a code example.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is create a dummy form that's the size of the control you want to print then add the control to the dummy form and show the form and print the control on the dummy.

Here is how i did it:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Create bitmap
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height);
    //Create form
    Form f = new Form();
    //add datagridview to the form
    f.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
    //set the size of the form to the size of the datagridview
    f.Size = dataGridView1.Size;
    //draw the datagridview to the bitmap
    dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height));
    //dispose the form
    f.Dispose();
    //print
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```